# Opening a text file in C++ windows 8.1 and msvc 2013

Tags: c++, windows-8, fstream

I'm trying to simply open a text file from my program.  But I'm having several strange issues.

For one the escape sequences not escaping...

const char* "D:\\assest\thing.txt"  = D:\\assest\thing.txt
and

const char* "D:\\Assest\thing.txt"  = D:Assest\\thing.txt
but

WHY DO TWO SLASHES ONLY GIVE ME ONE SLASH ON THIS FORUM, THAT SEEMS REALLY UNNECESSARY!

const char* "D:\assest\thing.txt"  = D:\assest\thing.txt  The correct path, I can copy that right from the debugger drop it into a file browser and the file pops right up, but std::ifstream(filePath) and std::ifstream::open(filePath); fail. As well as fopen_s.

I even tried to concatenate the string using the ascii code for / but gave up after I allocated all my memory only find strcat is depreciated, apparently Microsoft is trying to depreciate C. I guess after all the success of windows 8 they figured they should let it ride.

I was originally using strings but starting using char arrays after the same issues above.

Ive tried other text files and even putting the file into about every single folder in the project directory(though that does me no good anyway but I figured I had to try).

No file will not open any circumstance I can imagine.  I run the compiler as an admin, tried reading different files.  Restarting the computer, rubbing a magic lamp.  I'm out of ideas

Is there a trick I am missing, could my environment be to blame?

Code

```
std::string path = "C:\assest\rock.txt";
obj.readOBJ(path);

void objImporter::readOBJ(std::string filePath)
{
std::ifstream OBJfile(filePath);
//OBJfile.open(filePath.c_str());

if (OBJfile.is_open())
{
```

blah, blah , blah

```
OBJfile.close();
```

Does anyone have any insight at all??

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the escape sequences *are* working. `\a` is the beep character, `\r`is carriage return. You should escape your backslash (`\\`) like so:

```
string path = "c:\\assets\\rock.txt";
```

Comment: thank you for the response, The question has been updating due to ironic problems with \\\'s on my initial post...